# Why is this matrix not diagonalizable over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Consider  this matrix ( I don't know what mistake i am making in mathjax, I have thought a lot) ( Its a 3 * 3 matrix with 1 st row 2 ,2, 1 )

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 & 1  \\
   0 & 2 & -1   \\
 0 & 0 & 3   \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Question was asked in my algebra quiz that is this diagonalizable over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Eigenvalues of A are 2,2,3 $\in  \mathbb{Q}$ . So, why it is not diagonizable.

I seriosly have no idea!

Can you please tell why it is not diagonizable.

Comment: Can you find two linearly independent eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $2$?

Comment: @Tim Just as a remark on (proper) terminology, the elegant way to refer to a matrix of $m$ rows and $n$ columns is to say it has *type* $(m, n)$. When in particular $m=n$ we say that the matrix is *square of order* $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is not diagonalizable over $\Bbb Q$ because it is not diagonalizable at all (i.e. not diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$). It suffices to note that even though $2$ is an eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity $2$, the geometric multiplicity (dimension of the eigenspace) is
$$
\dim \ker (A - 2 I) = 1.
$$